# How do they keep maintaining the same dubbing voice in TV shows which longs for several years?

Tags: animation, dubbing, voice-acting

Like 'Powerpuff Girls', all the characters seems to have the same voice after many years. Due to aging, their voices will be changed especially with kids. But how did they get the same voice after 10 15 years?

Comment: Normally they use adult voice actors for children.

Comment: Have you done any direct comparisons of early seasons to later ones? I've had the occasional jolt when watching an older episode of, say, The Simpsons, and the voices are just a little off.

Comment: Yes, @user1118321 I could figure out the difference. But voices like 'Mayor' in Powerpuff Girls is difficult to find. Mimicking for a long time will be an ache in throat I believe. So, finding matching voices only they could do right?

Comment: WRT Powerpuff Girls: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DnyCSTpsq1E

Comment: @user1118321: That can also sometimes be a matter of artistic direction changing over time. Homer was initially a backup character to Bart (as the oaf father, similar to how Marge is currently still mostly a supporting character), but due to popularity, he eventually overtook Bart as the comic relief. Homer's comedy timing (and general wackiness) has significantly improved since he became more of a foreground character, which also reflects on how they voice him. But there are indeed also cases where the voices slowly changed over time (Marge, Lisa) for no real artistic reason.

Comment: @user1118321 - Per the commentaries on *The Simpsons*, some changes have been a matter of better fitting the characters as they developed (Homer may be an example of that), while others are simply a matter of preserving the actors; voices, as the original voice strained them. This might be part of the reason for the change in Homer (who Dan Castellaneta originally did as a Walter Matthau impression), and I think Moe. It's probably true for multiple characters who originally had one or two lines per show, and later got more significant roles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the case of the Simpsons, all of the main characters have been voiced by adults, and the same adults have voiced the same characters since the show started.

As for the Powerpuff Girls, many different actors have voiced the main characters.  [This site](http://www.behindthevoiceactors.com/tv-shows/The-Powerpuff-Girls/side-by-side/) shows each of the characters alongside the current actors who voice them. Under those pictures is another link showing how many other people have voiced the role during different seasons.  For example, [Blossom has been voiced by 6 different actors.](http://www.behindthevoiceactors.com/tv-shows/The-Powerpuff-Girls/Blossom/)

[image: main cast of Powerpuff Girls]

To re-cast a main character, the producers of the show need to audition actors who can mimic the character's voice very closely. Many trained voice actors will have the skill of impersonation, since their voice is their "tool" (similar to the way that a stunt person's "tool" is his/her body strength, reflexes, agility, flexibility, and so on).

Comment: Your link seems to contradict what you are saying. Those "6 different actors" are voice actors in different languages, not for different seasons of the show. The only recast of the main characters were with the 2016 reboot.